# Grouping Numbers in a similar range

Tags: mysql, math, group-by

I have these records

```
   id| num
   1 | 2.21231
   2 | 2.21234
   3 | 2.21228
   4 | 3.452
   5 | 3.45205
   6 | 3.45195
```

I'd like to group select items where there is a difference of .00005 or less so in this case 1 & 2, 1 & 3, 4 & 5, 4 & 6 OR if this is not possible (1,2,3) and (3,4,5)
Is this possible just with mysql?

**EDIT** 
Excluded possibilities

- `ROUND`: false negative `0.00004` and `0.00005`
- `TRUNCATE`, `FLOOR` and `CEIL`:  false positive `0.00001` and `0.00009` false negative `0.00009` and `0.0011`

Answer (score 3):

You mean, like this? :

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t2.id
  FROM the_table t1
  JOIN the_table t2
    ON t1.id < t2.id
   AND ABS(t1.num - t2.num) <= .00005
;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by with [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) function like:

```
select ..... group by TRUNCATE(num, 4);
```

Comment: if i group by round then 1.00004 and 1.00006 would not be in the same group

Comment: if you truncate 1.00011 and 1.00009 are not grouped, thanks for not giving up :D

Comment: i think you cant do it with a simple build-in function, what you want to do if you have 3 numbers like 1.00011 and 1.00015 and 1.00019 ?

Comment: the closet thing i do something like select ..... group by TRUNCATE(num + 0.00005, 4);